# In my project i wanna auto delete the data from the database after a fixed interval of time

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

In my project i wanna auto delete the data from the database after a fixed interval of time say (30 days); Is there any  automatic process to  delete the data  from the database without the user intervention..

i use nest js and postgres.

i try to use createdAt but never worked.

Comment: You can write a archival script and schedule a cron job to remove the required amount of data

Answer (score 0):

Postgresql does not have a TTL function for data. You will be better off writing a cron job. Or better yet you can use nestjs-scheduler to write the cron job. Refer to [Documentation of nestjs-scheduler](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/task-scheduling#task-scheduling)